# Git compressing jpeg's - does this cause quality loss?

Tags: git, jpeg

When I git push, it compresses all my commits first. Some of the files are jpeg's. I heard somewhere that jpeg's aren't lossless compression, so does this mean that the quality lowers every time I push an image?

Comment: Already answered, but I will add a side comment: in general, attempting to compress an already-compressed file will tend not to achieve much, and may even wind up making it bigger.  (If it *does* get a lot smaller, that means the original compression was inferior in some way ... although certain compression techniques are quite domain-specific, e.g., one might compress a photo of the Mona Lisa very well by replacing it with the phrase "a photo of the Mona Lisa", but we don't expect image-compressors to do this. :-) )

Answer (score 2):

What makes you think that git compresses your jpeg's ?
In fact don't worry: Git will not lower the quality of your photo. Git is designed to securely store whatever files you put in it so the quality will not decrease.

You may talk about git compressing your file because internally git will use compression to be faster but this is none of your business and it is lossless (so your lossy jpeg will still be lossy, but not more ;).

Answer (score 0):

GIT uses a lossless compression. Else you would loose some of your code at every submit.

Also the compression GIT uses is completely independent of the compression of any already compressed file. See it as a box in a box: Why would the inner box be affected by the extra box placed around it?